# Walk through multiple nested nodes via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a site that is generated from an TEI XML document, one of the elements of which is a set of thumbnail images at the top taken from the number of jpgs present in the file. The XML that contains those jpgs is as follows:

```
<sourceDoc xml:id="TextContent">
    <surfaceGrp xml:id="wall" n="South Wall">
        <surface xml:id="p.1" n="panel">
            <label>Verse 27</label>
            <graphic url="sw_test_1.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.30">
            <label>Verse 30</label>
            <graphic url="sw_test_2.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.27">
            <label>Verse 27</label>
            <graphic url="sw_test_3.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.56">
            <label>Verse 56</label>
            <graphic url="sw_test_4.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.57">
            <label>Verse 57</label>
            <graphic url="sw_test_5.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.58">
            <label>Verse 58</label>
            <graphic url="sw_test_6.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.59">
            <label>Verse 59</label>
            <graphic url="sw_test_7.jpg"/>
        </surface>
    </surfaceGrp>
</sourceDoc>
```

I'm applying the following rather messy piece of XSL to it, which works well with the code as it exists above and utilizes the tei namespace:

```
    <xsl:template name="menuWidth">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//tei:sourceDesc[1]/@xml:id='Clopton_Chantry_Chapel'">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">panel</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">page</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="menuHeader">
        <xsl:variable name="filename_length" select="string-length(tei:graphic/@url)"/>
        <h1 class="menuHeader">
            <xsl:call-template name="menuWidth"/>

            <div id="centerMenu">
                <xsl:apply-templates select=".././/tei:graphic" mode="list"/>
            </div>

            <xsl:variable name="last_block" as="xs:integer">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="//tei:sourceDesc[1]/@xml:id='Clopton_Chantry_Chapel'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::tei:surfaceGrp)"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(../../preceding-sibling::tei:surfaceGrp)"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>     
            </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="next_block" as="xs:integer">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="//tei:sourceDesc[1]/@xml:id='Clopton_Chantry_Chapel'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(../following-sibling::tei:surfaceGrp)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(../../following-sibling::tei:surfaceGrp)"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="total_blocks">
            <xsl:value-of select="../last()"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="group_position" as="xs:integer">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="//tei:sourceDesc[1]/@xml:id='Clopton_Chantry_Chapel'">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="../../count(tei:surfaceGrp) - count(../following-sibling::node()/position())"
                    />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="../../../count(tei:surfaceGrp) - count(../following-sibling::node()/position())"
                    />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>     
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="last_item_id">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="//tei:sourceDesc[1]/@xml:id='Clopton_Chantry_Chapel'">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="../../tei:surfaceGrp[last()]/tei:surface[last()]/@xml:id"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="../../../tei:surfaceGrp[last()]/tei:surfaceGrp[last()]/tei:surface[last()]/@xml:id"
                    />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>            
        </xsl:variable>

        <div id="rightMenu">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(preceding-sibling::tei:surface)+1 &gt; 1">
                    <span class="menuitem" id="previousItem">
                        <a class="nav_link">
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:value-of
                                    select="concat(substring(preceding-sibling::*[1]/tei:graphic/@url,1,($filename_length - 4)),'.html')"/>
                                <!--<xsl:value-of select="concat(preceding-sibling::*[1]/@xml:id,'.html')"/></xsl:attribute>-->
                            </xsl:attribute> Previous</a>
                    </span>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="count(../preceding-sibling::tei:surfaceGrp)+1 &gt; 1">
                    <span class="menuitem" id="previousItem">
                        <a class="nav_link"><xsl:attribute name="href">
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="concat(substring(../../tei:surfaceGrp[$last_block]/tei:surface[last()]/tei:graphic/@url,1,($filename_length - 4)),'.html')"
                            />
                        </xsl:attribute>Previous</a>
                    </span>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <span class="menuitem" id="previousItem">
                        <a class="nav_link">Previous</a>
                    </span>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$last_item_id = @xml:id">
                    <span class="menuitem" id="nextItem">
                        <a class="nav_link">Next</a>
                    </span>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="position() = last()">
                    <span class="menuitem" id="nextItem">
                        <a class="nav_link"><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of
                            select="concat(substring(../../tei:surfaceGrp[$group_position+1]/tei:surface[1]/tei:graphic/@url,1,($filename_length - 4)),'.html')"
                        /></xsl:attribute>Next</a>
                    </span>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="not(position() = last())">
                    <span class="menuitem" id="nextItem">
                        <a class="nav_link"><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of
                            select="concat(substring(following-sibling::*[1]/tei:graphic/@url,1,($filename_length - 4)),'.html')"
                        /></xsl:attribute>Next</a>
                    </span>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise/>
            </xsl:choose>
        </div>
    </h1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:graphic"/>

<xsl:template match="tei:graphic" mode="list">
    <span class="menuitem" id="image_thumbnail">
        <a class="nav_link">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(@url,1,string-length(@url)-4),'.html')"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <img class="thumbnail">
                <xsl:attribute name="src">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat('../../',$title_folder,'/',$witness,'/',$thumbnail_folder,'/',substring(@url,1,string-length(@url)-4),'-thumbnail.jpg')"
                    />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                    <xsl:value-of select="../tei:label"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </img>
        </a>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

This code works really well with a single `surfaceGrp` statement, as the first picture shows, but when I have to wrap the `surfaceGrp` in another `surfaceGrp` it only works with the innermost `surfaceGrp`.  My thought was that if I went up one more level via a `../` in the `group_position` variable it would display all of the items, but that doesn't seem to work, as shown by the second picture.

[image: First Picture] [image: Second Picture]

Ideally, what I want the HTML the XSL generates to look like is something like this, where each item's thumbnail image displays:

```
<div id="centerMenu">
<span class="menuitem" id="image_thumbnail">
    <a class="nav_link" href="sw_test_1.jpg">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="../../Quis_Dabit/Clopton/Thumbnails/sw_test_1-thumbnail.jpg" alt="First Panel" />
    </a>
</span>
<span class="menuitem" id="image_thumbnail">
    <a class="nav_link" href="sw_test_2.html">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="../../Quis_Dabit/Clopton/Thumbnails/sw_test_2-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Second Panel" />
    </a>
</span>
<span class="menuitem" id="image_thumbnail">
    <a class="nav_link" href="sw_test_3.html">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="../../Quis_Dabit/Clopton/Thumbnails/sw_test_3-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Third Panel" />
    </a>
</span>
<span class="menuitem" id="image_thumbnail">
    <a class="nav_link" href="sw_test_4.html">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="../../Quis_Dabit/Clopton/Thumbnails/sw_test_4-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Fourth Panel" />
    </a>
</span>
<span class="menuitem" id="image_thumbnail">
    <a class="nav_link" href="sw_test_5.html">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="../../Quis_Dabit/Clopton/Thumbnails/sw_test_5-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Fifth Panel" />
    </a>
</span>
<span class="menuitem" id="image_thumbnail">
    <a class="nav_link" href="sw_test_6.html">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="../../Quis_Dabit/Clopton/Thumbnails/sw_test_6-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Sixth Panel" />
    </a>
</span>
</div>
<div id="rightMenu">
    <span class="menuitem" id="previousItem">
        <a class="nav_link">Previous</a>
    </span>
    <span class="menuitem" id="nextItem">
        <a class="nav_link" href="sw_test_2.html">Next</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Even when the `surfaceGrp` wrap occurs in the middle of the list:

```
<sourceDoc xml:id="TextContent">
    <surfaceGrp xml:id="wall" n="West Wall">
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.60">
            <label>Verse 60</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_1.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.63">
            <label>Verse 63</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_2.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.65">
            <label>Verse 65</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_3.jpg"/>
        </surface>
    </surfaceGrp>
    <surfaceGrp xml:id="wall" n="West Wall">
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.66">
            <label>Verse 66</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_4.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.68">
            <label>Verse 68</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_5.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.69">
            <label>Verse 69</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_6.jpg"/>
        </surface>
    </surfaceGrp>
</sourceDoc>
```

What would be the best way to modify my code to achieve this?

Comment: I've seen a lot of really bad questions, but this one takes first prize. Your sample input document bears absolutely no relationship to your supplied xslt stylesheet. The given stylesheet is using an undefined prefix (`tei:`) which is not even present in the sample input. If you compare the sample input with the expected output, there is no linkage that any reader could see. If you want a solution, you have to provide one or more good test cases. A test case is a sample input paired with an expected output for that input, and clarity about how the two are related.

Comment: Thank you for the points.  I have edited the question to hopefully provide some additional context.  Please let me know if things are still unclear.

Comment: You do not "walk through" nodes in XSLT. The XSLT engine does the walking for you, invoking your templates on matching items. Do not program XSLT in imperative fashion, using `call-template` and `for-each` and `choose`. Write the templates for each pattern you want to match, and let XSLT do the work. Throw away your program and start over again keeping these principles in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is still very unclear to me, so this will not be exactly what you want, but it may point you in the right direction.

This XSLT 2.0 stylesheet ....

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="html" version="5" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Source Doc</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="sourceDoc" />
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sourceDoc">
  <div id="centerMenu">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="surfaceGrp/surface"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="surface">
  <span class="menuitem" id="{@xml:id}">
    <a class="nav_link" href="{graphic/@url}">
      <img
          class="thumbnail"
          src="{graphic/@url}"
          alt="First Panel" />
    </a>
  </span>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

... will transform this input xml document ...

```
<sourceDoc xml:id="TextContent">
    <surfaceGrp xml:id="wall" n="South Wall">
        <surface xml:id="p.1" n="panel">
            <label>Verse 27</label>
            <graphic url="sw_test_1.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.30">
            <label>Verse 30</label>
            <graphic url="sw_test_2.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.27">
            <label>Verse 27</label>
            <graphic url="sw_test_3.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.56">
            <label>Verse 56</label>
            <graphic url="sw_test_4.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.57">
            <label>Verse 57</label>
            <graphic url="sw_test_5.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.58">
            <label>Verse 58</label>
            <graphic url="sw_test_6.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.T.59">
            <label>Verse 59</label>
            <graphic url="sw_test_7.jpg"/>
        </surface>
    </surfaceGrp>
</sourceDoc>
```

... into this html output document ...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Source Doc</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="centerMenu">

        <span class="menuitem" id="p.1">
          <a class="nav_link" href="sw_test_1.jpg">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="sw_test_1.jpg" alt="First Panel">
          </a>
        </span>

        <span class="menuitem" id="EETS.T.30">
          <a class="nav_link" href="sw_test_2.jpg">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="sw_test_2.jpg" alt="First Panel">
          </a>
        </span>

        <span class="menuitem" id="EETS.T.27">
          <a class="nav_link" href="sw_test_3.jpg">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="sw_test_3.jpg" alt="First Panel">
          </a>
        </span>

        <span class="menuitem" id="EETS.T.56">
          <a class="nav_link" href="sw_test_4.jpg">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="sw_test_4.jpg" alt="First Panel">
          </a>
        </span>

        <span class="menuitem" id="EETS.T.57">
          <a class="nav_link" href="sw_test_5.jpg">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="sw_test_5.jpg" alt="First Panel">
          </a>
        </span>

        <span class="menuitem" id="EETS.T.58">
          <a class="nav_link" href="sw_test_6.jpg">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="sw_test_6.jpg" alt="First Panel">
          </a>
        </span>

        <span class="menuitem" id="EETS.T.59">
          <a class="nav_link" href="sw_test_7.jpg">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="sw_test_7.jpg" alt="First Panel">
          </a>
        </span>

      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking another look at it.  This does most of what I need, but I'm thinking I may need to step back and ask the question a bit more abstractly rather than trying to save the code I've already written in some form.